# MySQL 'AND' gives me error

Tags: mysql

I want to reduce the exact value when sale an item from items_on_rep table. And sales values should added to sales_details table

MY ITEMS_ON_REP TABLE
[image: items_on_reps]

MY SALES_DETAILS_TABLE
[image: sales_details]

Comment: can you share some piece of your code please?

Comment: @pes502 thanks for the update. This request has been fulfiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need mysql UPDATE query on the items_on_reps table.

first get the Qty value from items_on_reps table then subtract the value that is purchased (if its smaller than the qty on the table) then update the table with the new value.

do the same... now instead of update in the sales_details table you create a row and add the purchased qty in there and then add the details you previously grabbed in the query (e.g. name, purchased qty, and price)